# PC doesn't dectect my old soundcard

Tags: audio, sound-card, input, audio-output

My old soundcard was not working not properly and I decided to buy new one. I installed the new one and it works good but the mic input has some kind of cracking sound (I think that I have some problem with the power supply, because when I touch my PC box with a jack there is some kind of spark coming out) . Now I want to use my old soundcard for the mic input and the new one for the sounds output, but my PC only monitors the new soundcard. The old soundcard is on the motherboard, can this be the problem ?